# Wordpress - Chrome not loading ajax googleapis securely -

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome

Wordpress site in Chrome (not Firefox) is blocking jquery loading - console shows error in our recently secured (full site) over SSL.

> "The page was loaded over HTTPS, but displayed insecure content from 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS."

When I view it in Firefox, this same call is indeed HTTPS.

I see the call to this URL in the head section of the page source, but haven't located where this call is coming from in the code so I can change it to HTTPS.  Getting generated... But where? I can't locate it.
Our WordPress Address (URL) and the Site Address (URL) are both HTTPS - all else works except for this jquery call.

I have read similar issues on this forum but don't know clear way to fix it within Wordpress or force the HTTPS... or even find what's calling it - at the limits of my knowledge about this... Thanks for any help here

Comment: use `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js` to load the javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js` to load the javascript, instead of adding the `http` or `https` protocol in front of the url. Modern browsers know to prepend the proper protocol when non is supplied.

That being said, since you are using WordPress, you should have one of the latest versions of jQueryUI already in the installation. You simply need to `wp_enqueue_script()` the ones you need. For instance, if you need draggable and sortable, you would use `wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-draggable');` and `wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-sortable');` respectively. WordPress is kept pretty up to date on these APIs, so offloading jQueryUI to googleapis is probably not the best of ideas, because you could incur a page load time hit by adding another domain for a browser to lookup.